# JSON.parse only part of object

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I'm trying to parse the following JSON returned from a server:

```
{
"plant_1":{
    "name":"agi_1",
    "growth":[{"d":0,"m":20,"w":2,"n":"10"}]},
"plant_2":{
    "name":"agi_2",
    "growth":[{"d":0,"m":20,"w":2,"n":"20"}]},
"plant_3":{
    "name":"agi_3",
    "growth":[{"d":0,"m":20,"w":2,"n":"30"}]},
"plant_4":{
    "name":"agi_4",
    "growth":[{"d":0,"m":20,"w":2,"n":"40"}]},
"plant_5":{
    "name":"agi_5",
    "growth":[{"d":0,"m":20,"w":2,"n":"50"}]}
}
```

*(code formatted for ease of reading, there's no newline char)*

Directly parsing the JSON returns the following object :

[image]

As you can see, `plant_1.growth` is empty, while the others have the corresponding object in the array.

Copying the above string and doing `JSON.parse` on the string (e.g. `JSON.parse('string')`) works fine and returns the correct model.

I have no idea what's going on, as the JSON is valid. Any idea how to recover the model correctly?

**EDIT 1**

I'm using Express server and Mongoskin to query the Mongo database and return the requested data. Below is the DB query code :

```
db.collection('plants').find({owner : owner}, function(err, result) {
    if(err) throw err;

    var idx = 1;
    result.each(function(err, doc) {

        if(doc != null) {

            obj['plant_' + idx] = {
                name : doc.name,
                growth : doc.growth 
            }

            idx = idx + 1;

        } else {

            console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
            res.send(JSON.stringify(obj));

        }

    });

});
```

result of `console.log(JSON.stringify(obj))` :

```
{"plant_1":{"name":"agi_1","growth":[{"d":0,"m":20,"w":2,"n":"10"}]},"plant_2":{"name":"agi_2","growth":[{"d":0,"m":20,"w":2,"n":"20"}]},"plant_3":{"name":"agi_3","growth":[{"d":0,"m":20,"w":2,"n":"30"}]},"plant_4":{"name":"agi_4","growth":[{"d":0,"m":20,"w":2,"n":"40"}]},"plant_5":{"name":"agi_5","growth":[{"d":0,"m":20,"w":2,"n":"50"}]}}
```

**EDIT 2**

Code used to request and process request

```
    // Get plants data synchronously
var conn = new XMLHttpRequest();
conn.open("POST", "get-plants", false);

conn.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
conn.onreadystatechange = function() {

    console.log(conn.responseText)   // Line 53
    var response = JSON.parse(conn.responseText);
    console.log(response);          // Line 55

    if(conn.readyState == 4 && conn.status == 200) { 

        if(response != null) {

            thatGame.plants = response;

        } else {
            // empty
            console.log('invalid');
        }
    }

};  
conn.send(JSON.stringify({owner : game.state.states['Main'].user}));

console.log(this.plants.plant_1);    // Line 74
```

And a screenshot of browser `console`.

[image]

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: How do you know that exactly this data you posted is returned from the server?

Comment: I can't see any issue with parsing that JSON string. I just ran it in my console and plant_1.growth isn't empty. See screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/keUx28C.jpg

Comment: How is the JSON being loaded from the server. When you inspect the call in the server, do you see what you think you are returning?

Comment: Are you assigning some values to this object? If you are overwriting it in somewhere it might lead to this problem...

Comment: Unrelated, but `res.send(JSON.stringify(obj))` is not as good as `res.json(obj)` (clearer, shorter, also sets your content type correctly).

Comment: What does your Developer Tools Network panel say, which version is actually transmitted?

Comment: @Amadan I'm sending a POST XHR request to `/get-plants` which returns correctly (status 200). `console.log(conn.responseText)` returns the correct JSON above. What's baffling me is why is `JSON.parse` not returning the object in the `plant_1`'s array while correctly returning the others,

Comment: @FelixKling that's the baffling part :) I ran the returned JSON string using console's `JSON.parse` and returns the object correctly. However, a direct call to `JSON.parse(conn.responseText)` from the XHR query is missing an object in `plant_1`'s array

Comment: put `debugger;` immediately after `console.log(JSON.parse(conn.responseText));` and verify that the object is correct immediately after the parse. You might be changing the object later, and `console.log` sometimes takes a bit of time (so your rendered object is different from the time when you called `console.log`).

Comment: For example, test this in console: `var obj = ....; console.log(obj); o.plant_1.growth = [];` - it will almost certainly report that `o.plant_1.growth` is empty, even though you are modifying it after `console.log`. So if you want to see exact data in the object at that moment, either stop the program using `debugger`, or print `JSON.stringify(obj)`, so you get a string that won't change while being rendered. (Just guessing, but you changing the object after `console.log` is the only thing that I can think of.)

Comment: @Amadan I think you're correct. I've updated the question with result after adding `debugger;` after `console.log(JSON.parse(conn.responseText))`.

Putting `debugger` after `console.log(JSON.parse(conn.responseText))` shows the correct properties, and I can pop the object in the array even when `console.log` says there's nothing in it.

Comment: If you're popping from the array, that's the very reason there's nothing in it. :) `console.log` is just showing you the future state.

Comment: @Amadan ohh.. okay.. I just knew that. I thought `console.log` would post the current status of the object. Thanks for the help! :)