# Angular 8 JSON.parse not parsing completely/impartially

Tags: json, angular

I receive a JSON object that looks like this:
this data is being passed through a Socketio emit, so the angular HttpClient is not intercepting it.

```
{
  "single":[
    {
      "name":"Xavi555",
      "data":[
        {
          "_id":"5e2ea609f8c83e5435ebb6e5",
          "id":"test1",
          "author":"someone",
          "recipient":"someone",
          "content":"test",
          "msgId":"Testid",
          "gNamespace":""
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "group":[]
}
```

however when I use `JSON.parse()` on the object above The key `data` does not contain the value of `data` that is to say:

```
private func(jsonObj: string): void {
  console.log(jsonObj);
}
```

I see:

```
single: Array(1)
groups: Array(0)
```

```
single Array(1)
  name: test
  data: Array(0)
```

I thought it was an issue with deep cloning, but, when trying to do `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(jsonObj))` it returns the original json string object.
[related but no solution posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32575395/json-parse-only-part-of-object?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[image: screen shot]
actual code:

```js
private handleStoredMessages(dirtyObj: string): void {
  // debugger;
  const cleanObj = JSON.parse(dirtyObj);
   const { single, group } = cleanObj;

   console.log('raw json', dirtyObj);
   onsole.log('clean json', cleanObj);
}
```

any ideas?

Comment: you originally get the `JSON Object` so why you are converting the `JSON` to `String` and then again you are parsing the `JSON`, What is the purpose of that? and you can only parse the `JSON String` if you did't pass the `JSON Sting` it will throw the error "does not contain the value of data"

Comment: as I said, I was doing the stringingify in the parse to see if it was a cloning issue, which it isn't, so I am no longer doing that

Comment: Did you try to inspect your `cleanObj` using a debugger right after `const cleanObj = JSON.parse(dirtyObj);` ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using angular, then I doubt you should be using `JSON.parse`. This is handled by the `HttpClient`. Nevertheless, your assumption about your data structure is wrong. The `single` is an array of objects, not an object itself:

So to access the `.data` you need to do `jsonObj.single[0].data`. Which in itself is an array again

---

The only other reason this could happen, is because you modify the object/array somewhere else in your code, before you actually press the triangle in console to open the object. Hover on the blue information icon to see why.

> Value below was evaluated just now

The object is lazily evaluated, meaning that if you did any transformations to the object, it will show that state, not the state at the moment you logged the object.

Comment: I am using angular, the data that is being passed in is through Socket.io as JSON string, and yes, sorry, meant to say array of objects*... the

Comment: @Ctfrancia I've updated my answer with another plausible cause to your issue

Answer (score 0):

The issue of this was that the back end guy double encoded and did some weird stuff not my fault